# How to define a relationship in bookshelf.js model with a junction table?

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

I'm having trouble understanding how to define relationships in my bookshelf models.

This is the schema for my tables:

```
account table

+----+-------------+
| id |  username   |
+----+-------------+
| 30 | someuser    |
| 31 | anotheruser |
| 32 | dude        |
+----+-------------+

employee table

+----+-------------------+
| id |       email       |
+----+-------------------+
|  2 | some@one.com      |
|  3 | fake@employee.com |
+----+-------------------+

account_manager table

+----+------------+-------------+
| id | account_id | employee_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |         30 |           2 |
|  2 |         31 |           3 |
|  3 |         32 |           3 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

The documentation for bookshelf is a little hard to follow, but this seems like it should be doing what I want, but isn't.

```
class Account extends Bookshelf.Model {

  manager() {
    return this.hasOne('Employee').through('AccountManager');
  }

}

class Employee extends Bookshelf.Model {

  accounts() {
    return this.hasMany('Account').through('AccountManager');
  }

}

class AccountManager extends Bookshelf.Model {

  account() {
    return this.hasOne('Account', 'id');
  }



  employee() {
    return this.hasMany('Employee', 'id');
  }

}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Account
.forge()
.fetch({ withRelated: ['manager'] })
.then((accounts) => { ... });
```

And get a result of:

```
[
  {
    id: 30,
    username: 'someuser',
    manager: {
      id: 2,
      email: 'some@one.com',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    username: 'anotheruser',
    manager: {
      id: 3,
      email: 'fake@employee.com',
    },
  },
];
```

How do I setup my models to do this? It seems like it should be pretty simple but I've yet to find a good example (something showing the SQL schema table being referenced in the model would help a lot) of defining relationships with a junction table. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.